# How do I add the same scrapy pipeline to any spider in scrapyd

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I have several projects running in [scrapyd](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd) and all uses the same pipeline, so How can I add this pipeline to every scheduled spider as default with out adding anything to the curl request, only having a flag in `default_scrapyd.conf` file?

Comment: I'm afraid there are only two options and you already rejected one of them. The other options is to add the pipeline in `ITEM_PIPELINES` in each of the projects' `settings.py` and re-deploy projects.

Comment: one question, the other options is call the pipeline in the ``curl`` request right? but I must add the pipeline in each project anyways?

Comment: Yeah, the other option is to override `ITEM_PIPELINES` setting on curl command line.